# Android Proper Place to Store User Info

Tags: android, session, authentication, sharedpreferences

After a user has logged in, I would like to keep the user data in a place that can be access by all activities, such as firstname, lastname, ID and the status that a user has logged in.
Should I store them in a SharedPreferences or the class that extends Application?
Or should I keep a SharedPreferences in the class that extends Application?
I don't know which one is a good style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used SharedPreferences, that would make it available to for backup

Answer (score 1):

**Shared Preference** is the Best Way to keep the logging status so that you can clear that on logout also.Keeping The shared preference in a class extends application is good so that you can use that statically around the app also try to store the keywords of sharedvalues in a seperate static class.